# flutter UI grid

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, image-gallery

I want to build a grid likes the picture below, I tried using gridView.count but the photos was square, and I tried to use column and wrap inside it with the picture having AspectRatio class but it didn't also look like it, so any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the layout using a Staggered Grid View.

Check the package below:

[Flutter Staggered Grid View](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

Answer (score 0):

there is bunch of lib that you can use for this :

1. [waterfall_flow](https://pub.dev/packages/waterfall_flow)
2. [reorderableitemsview](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderableitemsview)
3. [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

I hope I hope I was able to help.